# Hardhat public network fork: Error calling view functions with ethers.js on browser

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, forks

I have my hardhat network configured as a fork of Binance Smart Chain like this:

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 500,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: chainIds.bscMainnet,
      forking: {
        url: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/",
        blockNumber: 31717026
      }
    },

(...)
```

The fork is working great and all the tests are passing with success.
Now, I'm trying to integrate the Smart Contract on the forked Hardhat network, with Ethers.js, connecting to it trough Metamask (RPC URL: `localhost:8545`).

I can execute all the functions that generate a transaction (send) with no problems (same code of automated tests) but when I try to call view functions, or public state variables, I always getting the following error:

```
ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert
exception (method="registry()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null,
errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION,
version=abi/5.2.0)
```

**UPDATE**

- I have updated Hardhat to latest version (2.17.3) and the error keeps
  the same.
- I can interact with contracts deployed in mainnet, accessing to view functions and state variables.

The problem only happens, trying to access view functions and state variables, from contracts deployed by myself in the locally forked BSC hardhat network. The error I see in the terminal, when I run the locally forked Blockchain is the following:

```
eth_call
  WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
  From:            0x...
  To:              0x...
```

**UPDATE 2**

My code (plain javascript in html for testing purposes):

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);


await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner();

let abi_registry = await fetch("./abis/Registry.json");
abi_registry = await abi_registry.json();
abi_registry = abi_registry.abi;
console.log(abi_registry);
const registryAddr = "0xf07eC5fa63F57Ef97D5155FeC1D09cDF14a78BaC";
const registryContract = new ethers.Contract(registryAddr, abi_registry, provider);


async function platformFeeRate(){
  let numVaults = await registryContract.numVaults();
  console.log(numVaults);
};
```

The error does not happen if I connect to contracts that are already deployed on a public network.

**UPDATE 3**

I have also tried avoiding `hardhat.config.ts` fork config, and starting a new fork node in the terminal, but I'm getting same result:

```
npx hardhat node --fork https://bsc.quiknode.pro/ --fork-block-number 31827701
```

Comment: what version of `hardhat` are you using? if you're on an older version you may want to upgrade to the latest(it's possible that this is a bug that has been fixed), also when was the contract you're trying to read deployed, was it before the configured block i.e. 31717026?

Comment: I have upgraded to latest hardhat version and the error keeps the same.
See my update above for more details (here takes too long).

Comment: Can you provide the BSC mainnet contracts that you're trying to interact with via the hardhat local fork?

Comment: The contracts I'm trying to interact with are contracts developed by me, not deployed in mainnet yet. If I interact with contracts deployed in mainnet, there is no problem.

Comment: I understand, but can you provide the problem contracts deployed on mainnet that you're trying to interact with?

Comment: There is no problem with contracts deployed on mainnet. I'm interacting with PancakeSwap Router v2 (0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E) without errors, trough my local hardhat's fork of BSC. The errors only appear when trying to interact with Smart Contracts desployed by me on my local hardhat's fork of BSC.

Comment: So I managed to interact with that contract in a local hardhat fork, however using the following node: https://binance.llamarpc.com, this is likely an archive node and so it can support the specific calls that the local hardhat fork requires whereas https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/ is likely a pruned node and cannot, though I get a different error than you i.e. `ProviderError: missing trie node`

Comment: Do you mean forking from https://binance.llamarpc.com? I'm getting same error when changing the URL. Are you using Web3Provider or JsonRpcProvider, with  ethers.js?

Comment: @AlexanderHerranz, It could be the archived node issue. BSC datafeed doesn't archive the blocks. try to use the provider form QuickNode. They've archived node.

Comment: I'm using typechain with ethers

Comment: @SaadSuri Same error using QuickNode...

Comment: @MShakeG me too using typechain with Ethers. You can see my code on UPDATE 2, but does not seem to be that, because it is working with contracts that are already deployed on mainnet.

Comment: can you share a repo with a minimal reproduction of the error?

Comment: @MShakeG https://github.com/Alexander-Herranz/hardhat-network-fork/ here you have a sample repo reproducing the error. In Readme.md you can see how to run the project (very easy) in order to see the error with RETRIEVE (view) function.

Comment: @AlexanderHerranz what am I supposed to run? I modified the deploy.ts to retrieveNum from the Storage contract and it works as expected?

Comment: I can run it programmatically with JavaScript (thought automated test). The problem arises when executing the web project (/metamask-html folder), with metamask in the web browser.

Comment: Even if I connect to the contract using the external provider (not Metamask), I get the same error trying to read public view functions. https://docs.ethers.org/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--connecting-rpc