# Fork specific blocknumber on BSC Mainnet call deployed contract failed

Tags: solidity, hardhat, foundry

I want to call Quoter Contract on BSC Mainnet which is deployed already.

I'm using HardHat or Foundry to fork Mainnet specific blocknumber, here is HardHat Config JS:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        // url: Also Try Using QuickNode API,
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8540",// Local Server is running Geth Service on 8540 port
        blockNumber: 31723542,//Trying to fork this blockNumber
        chainId: 56
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Or Using Foundry Anvil:

```
anvil --fork-url QuickNode's_HTTP_EndPoint --fork-block-number 31723542 --chain-id 56
```

My Test JS File

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const {ethers } = require('ethers')
//Quoter Address ABI JSON
jsonFile = "./bsc-quoter.json";
parsed = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFile));
var bscAbi = parsed
//bsc-quoter
bscQuoterAddress = '0xB048Bbc1Ee6b733FFfCFb9e9CeF7375518e25997'

const rpcURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8545"//Using Local HardHat or Foundry Fork
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcURL)


const bscQuoter = new ethers.Contract(
    bscQuoterAddress,
    bscAbi,
    provider
)

const main = async() => {
//Just Random Pick a V3Pool Address
    const params = {
        tokenIn:"0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955",
        tokenOut:"0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",

        amountIn:"91188",
        fee:500,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96:0
    }

    const amountOut = await bscQuoter.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(
        params
    )
    console.log('amountOut',amountOut['amountOut'].toString())
    
}

main()
```

This is BSC Mainnet Quoter Contract Address (Which is already deployed in previous block)

```
0xB048Bbc1Ee6b733FFfCFb9e9CeF7375518e25997
```

Then, I Just Call the js:

```
npx hardhat run ./quoter.js
//Or
npx hardhat run ./quoter.js --network localhost
```

It failed.

HardHat Fork Terminal log:

```
eth_accounts
eth_call
  WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
  From: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:   0xb048bbc1ee6b733fffcfb9e9cef7375518e25997
```

This Quoter is a Contract , I don't know why it failed.

But when forking without blocknumber, it success.

Comment: Your issue seems similar to this:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/154528/86303

Comment: @MShakeG emm, Yep seems similar, don't notice before. Maybe the same problem. I'm noob with DAPP dev, can't find any tech article to teach about this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To do a proper fork with Hardhat (or Foundry, or Truffle etc), you need to be forking a node that is *archive*. If you are forking a *full* node, you will have the state pruned. You normally also get a "missing trie" error from the full node on an attempt to fork, not sure why you are not getting that.

My suggestion is double-check that you are forking off an RPC endpoint of an archive node.

As an example, I just forked the chain with your settings (same block) but using a BSC mainnet *archive* node from Chainstack and then ran the following sample code (same contract) and it works. (I think your test.js needs some cleaning up, like web3 doesn't seem to be used etc).

Simple test code against the forked chain:

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

const contractAbi = ABI_OFF_ETHERSCAN

const contractAddress = '0xB048Bbc1Ee6b733FFfCFb9e9CeF7375518e25997';

const rpcURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8545";
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcURL);

const main = async () => {
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, provider);
    
    try {
        // Fetch the WETH9 address
        const weth9Address = await contract.WETH9();
        console.log("WETH9 Address:", weth9Address);

        // Fetch the deployer address
        const deployerAddress = await contract.deployer();
        console.log("Deployer Address:", deployerAddress);

        // Fetch the factory address
        const factoryAddress = await contract.factory();
        console.log("Factory Address:", factoryAddress);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error.message);
    }
}

main();
```